# Can't transfer EPF account due to pension contribution not present

Tags: india, pension, provident-fund

My previous employer has not submitted pension contribution for the initial months of my service. Now I can't transfer/withdraw my EPFO balance from my old PF account to my new PF account under the same UAN.

My current employer can't do anything and my previous employer keeps stalling the request. I tried reaching the PF office directly, but no one wants to even talk there. Can someone please suggest how can this error be resolved?

Any help/suggestions would be extremely helpful.

[image: Nil contribution to pension fund]

Comment: I am not getting your question. not contributed for initial months ?! you mean you did not get amount for initial months and you are following up with Your old company ?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from chasing EPFO, there is not much that can be done.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are a member of the EPF scheme since joining the job, but not the EPS scheme. You became an EPS member later. Check the date of joining EPF and EPS in your profile on the EPFO portal.

Now your new employer is using your old UAN then the fund balance will automatically get transferred from your old employer.
No need to worry about it.

Comment if any further questions.